# Multiply a SIMD vector of byte integers by a float

Tags: assembly, masm, sse

I am trying to calculate filter on image by multiplying pixel values by constant float value, like 0.533. I am willing to do it in MASM, by passing values of pixels stored as byte to XMM register (packed one value after another so like RGBARGBARGBARGBA). Then I want to use vector operation to maximize performance. I am using MASM x64

I cannot find any operation that can multiply byte value (range 0 to 255) by constant float. Is it even possible?

It's academical project so I have to meet that vector requirements

Comment: @nullqube: That's about software implementation of floating point math, totally unrelated to this.

Comment: The straightforward way to implement this is to unpack bytes to dwords and convert to FP and back for `mulps`.  (`_mm_cvtepu8_epi32` / `_mm_cvtepi32_ps` / `_mm_mul_ps` using C intrinsics.  Or if you really want to hand-write in asm for some reason, SSE4.1 `pmovzxbd` / `cvtdq2ps` / `mulps` / etc.)  But probably you only need to unpack to 16-bit for a fixed-point multiply if you don't mind an approximation of the float.  [How to load a pixel struct into an SSE register?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12121640) / comments on [Converting bytes to floats using simd](//stackoverflow.com/q/70651511)

Comment: No, there's no single instruction that scales integers by floats.  It is of course possible with multiple instructions.

Comment: If you also want to combine different channels and are ok with just 8bit precision for the multiplicand, you can often even use `pmaddubsw`/`_mm_maddubs_epi16`. If you write what you actually want, we may find a duplicate question.